# Using CI collation as case Sensitive in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, case-sensitive

I want to have both Persian and English letters in one of my Columns,

So I set the collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

But it is case-insensitive ...  How can I use it Case-sensitive?

(For example Wordpress uses utf8mb4_unicode_ci but it is still case-sensitive)

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the collation to `utf8mb4_bin`.

Comment: Perhaps `utf8mb4_bin` is microscopically more appropriate?

Comment: @Martin -- quite true.  Not just appropriate, but syntactically correct.